# Display results as groups by date, date as title for every group

Tags: sorting, grouping

Damn, there must be answers for this here but i have no idea where to search for.

I'm getting some data out of my database and group this by a date in one of the tables. This all works fine, but now i want a title with this date above every group. So something like this:

**27 januari**
- news 1
- news 2
- news 3
**26 januari**
- news 4
- news 5

etc. ect.

This is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
             vd.*, tbl.name, gs.game_title
        FROM
             vods vd
        INNER JOIN
             tabel tbl on vd.tabel_id = tbl.id
        LEFT JOIN 
             games gs on vd.game_id = gs.id
        WHERE 
             vd.active = 1 
        GROUP BY
             vd.tabel_date 
        ORDER BY 
             vd.tabel_date DESC";
```

Do i really have to run a query for each date? Or is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: This has got something to do with relational databases, right?

Comment: I  get the data from a mysql database, but it's more about how i get to print the data the way i want. Should i change something in my starting post? Is that not clear enough?

Comment: Well, your present query is nonsensical- but it's up to you